# Problem preventing form submission with jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I wish to execute a jquery based ajax form submission on pressing the enter key.  Obviously this involves stopping the normal form submission process.  My form consists of a single input field.  Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add vid ajax
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache:false;
    });
    var ajax_load = '<div class="displayBox">Adding url...</div>';
    var loadUrl = 'ajax/add';

    $("#vidForm").submit(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
        /*$("body").html(ajax_load)
        .load(loadUrl,{url:$("#addurl").value},function(responseText){
            $("#videos").append(responseText);
        });*/
        return false;
    });

});
</javascript>
...
<form id="vidForm" action="ajax/">  
    <input id="addurl" name="addurl"/>
</form>
```

I'd expect the above to submit to 'ajax/add' but it doesn't, submitting instead a full blown http-request to 'ajax' the default behaviour (in Chrome at least).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Well, if anything is broken in your javascript, you may not even be getting as far as the `submit()`... Do you see any errors in the console if your run this using a debugger such as Firebug?

Comment: It's well worth using some tools to help you with things. Look at using the Dev Tools that are part of Chrome or Safari (Ctrl+Shift+I), or installing Firebug on Firefox, or using the free Visual Studio environment for IE. Any of them would have pointed out several of the issues with that code.

Comment: no errors to report in firebug after fixing the 2 issues below

Comment: That's odd, see my updated answer -- that leaves very little to go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Now that you've cleared up the earlier issues, I'm not seeing any problem. Fundamentally, it works: http://jsbin.com/ugowa4  (Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera for Linux; IE6 and IE8.) You'll have to walk through with a debugger to figure out at what point things are failing. The basics should work.

---

Looks like you've forgotten to declare the event parameter:

```
$("#vidForm").submit(function(e){
                              ^--- Add this
```

Without it, you're trying to access a variable `e` from the containing scope. If there isn't one, or it doesn't have a function called `preventDefault`, you'll get an exception at that point and the rest of the function will be ignored.

See also Nick's note about the closing tag (should be `</script>`) and the misplaced `;`.

Comment: I had another small bit of javascript that apparently hid the failings of my code posted above; swapped their position and works ok now cheers

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, any JavaScript errors will probably result in the same behavior as *no JavaScript at all*, and that's what you're seeing...the *default* submission behavior because of script errors.  I've outlined the issues below:

Your closing tag is off:

```
</javascript>
```

should be:

```
</script>
```

---

Also object literals shouldn't have a `;` for properties, so change:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:false;
});
```

To:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:false
});
```

---

And lastly, remove this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Your `return false` is already taking care of this (and would error anyway because of the missing parameter, as in TJ's answer).

Comment: I removed the semi colon and the call to e.preventDefault().  The <javascript> was a typo in my question.  Still didn't get an alert box popping up, and default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any button with the type `submit` in the `form`? For example like

```
<form id="vidForm" action="ajax/">  
    <input id="addurl" name="addurl"/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

or

```
<form id="vidForm" action="ajax/">  
    <input id="addurl" name="addurl"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Clicking of the "Send" button in the example will submit the form. If you form has more elements please post the whole code.